# Always get "redirect_uri_mismatch" under google oauth progress

Tags: google-oauth

I am developing a website which need google-login button. But i failed in getting the access_token.
Here is my configuration page and curl result.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## why curl doesn't work.

The problem you are having is that you have created web browser credentials and you appear to be testing with curl.  Curl by itself would be run in a command prompt or shell script there for it would be installed credentials not web browser credentials.

Go to google developer console and create desktop app type creetinals Then you can follow the calls below in order to authorize to Google and get an access token and a refresh token.

Notice how desktop apps use urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob for a redirect uri this means just send it back where it came from.

```
# Client id from Google Developer console
# Client Secret from Google Developer console
# Scope this is a space separated list of the scopes of access you are requesting.

# Authorization link.  Place this in a browser and copy the code that is returned after you accept the scopes.
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=[Application Client Id]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=[Scopes]&response_type=code

# Exchange Authorization code for an access token and a refresh token.

curl \
--request POST \
--data "code=[Authentcation code from authorization link]&client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

# Exchange a refresh token for a new access token.
curl \
--request POST \
--data 'client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&refresh_token=[Refresh token granted by second step]&grant_type=refresh_token' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

code ripped from [GoogleAuthenticationCurl.sh](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/cff75182aac5fa42930a09f58b63a309)

YOu may also be interested in [Which type of credentials should you create?](https://youtu.be/eiiktPs5z50) which explains how to decide which type of Google credentials you need to use for the application you are developing.

## your web application.

Redirect uri mismatch with a true web application is most often a configuration issue.    If you are using a servicer sided programming language you simply need to take the redirect uri that the error message is telling you is wrong and place that in Google Developer console for your web application as a Redirect uri.  [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2](https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

If on the other hand you have a Client sided web application using javascript it will state that the issue is with the JavaScript origin.  It is still a configuration issue. However this time you need to take the URL it is telling you is wrong and place that in the javascript origin field in Google developer console [Simple solution for redirect_uri_mismatch error with JavaScript](https://youtu.be/V0-4LnHwFho)

YOu do not need both Redirect URI and Javascript origin its one or the other.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have found the reason and will attach it in the following answer

Comment: Please remember to accept my answer if it helped you.  As i mentioned the redirect uri must exactly match where you are sending it from, this appears to have been your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

The problem is that i have added two version of redirect uri in the google console:
http and https

In the first step, i redirect customer to the oauth page "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth" with http version redirect uri.

In the second step i try to got the access token with https version redirect uri, so i got this error.

Comment: I think this could have been a comment on my answer rather than your own answer.   You may want to consult [answer]